# Are rapid GET requests to same page normal traffic or a form of probing?

Tags: http2, safari

I'm getting multiple rapid-fire requests within 200 milliseconds (0.2 seconds) from IP addresses that all are assigned to ISPs. They consistently purport to be Safari running on MacOSX and it's never the same IP twice.

The user agents are consistently either: "Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_15_7)+AppleWebKit/605.1.15+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/16.0+Safari/605.1.15"

or: "Client/35574+CFNetwork/1474+Darwin/23.0.0"

It's always 1 page, or even just the favicon.ico file referenced through 1 page, dozens of times within 200ms. All of them are in the log with 200 status codes up until they hit the dynamic IP restrictions. I've been seeing it a few times a day on average for about a month in my log analysis.

The server is IIS and is up to date and I followed Microsoft recommendations regarding CVE-2023-44487 early last month.

Is this some kind of probing such as for DDoS vulnerabilities like the HTTP/2 rapid reset? Or is it just a Safari bug I can ignore?